# Error: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Trying to get a handle on Entity Framework here and I am hitting some speed bumps...
I have a Get() method that works fine and has been tested, but my Delete method is not working:

```
   public static void Delete(string name)
    {
        J1Entities db = new J1Entities();
        db.DeleteObject(Get(name));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But I get the following error: 
**Error: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.**

I ran the debugger, and the object inside the DeleteObject is correct... what am I missing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each EF object is tightly associated to the manager (for want of a better word) that created it. or to which it has been associated. Since you don't pass `db` to your `Get` method, I assume that `Get` has either used it's own `J1Entities`, or the object has been created standalone (perhaps deserialized).

In order to delete it, it must know about it *first*. That might mean by *attaching* an object to the manager - but in this case, it seems like an easier option is just to pass `db` into `Get`, so that the `Get` is done in the same context (since `db` will automatically attach objects that it creates itself).

Comment: Perfect...
I figured it was something simple... :)