# Error: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager. c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to remove data from a table `Ent_El_Tags{entel_id,tag_id}` and I face the error when i apply remove function to the relationship which I declared  as below but it works for Add functionality.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Ent_El_Tags> AddTagsToElements([FromUri]ParamsClass parameters)
    {
        var relationships = new List<Ent_El_Tags>();
        foreach (var el in parameters.element_ids)
        {
            foreach (var t_id in parameters.tag_ids)
            {

                var relationship = new Ent_El_Tags { entel_id = el, tag_id = t_id };
                relationships.Add(relationship);
                _context.Ent_El_Tags.Add(relationship);

            }

        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return relationships;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public List<Ent_El_Tags> DeleteTagsToElements([FromUri]ParamsClass parameters)
    {
        var relationships = new List<Ent_El_Tags>();           
        foreach (var el in parameters.element_ids)
        {
            foreach (var t_id in parameters.assigned_ids)
            {
                var relationship = new Ent_El_Tags { entel_id = el, tag_id = t_id };
                relationships.Add(relationship);
                _context.Ent_El_Tags.Remove(relationship);
            }
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return relationships;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: Did you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449740/error-the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatem

Answer (score 0):

To delete a record using EntityFramework, you need to get the record from database using EntityFramework, in that the object will be inside EF ObjectStateManager.

```
var relationship = new Ent_El_Tags { entel_id = el, tag_id = t_id };
_context.Ent_El_Tags.Remove(relationship);
```

replace this with

```
var relationship = _context.Ent_El_Tags.Where(x=>x.enterl_Id==el && x.tag_id==t_id).FirstOrDefault();
_context.Ent_El_Tags.Remove(relationship);
```